# Redux Framework get text from select field instead of id (key)

Tags: php, templates, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to get the text in options instead of the id ("key")? For example.

```
$fields = array(
    'id'       => 'opt-select',
    'type'     => 'select',
    'title'    => __('Select Option', 'redux-framework-demo'), 
    'subtitle' => __('No validation can be done on this field type', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'desc'     => __('This is the description field, again good for additional info.', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    // Must provide key => value pairs for select options
    'options'  => array(
        '1' => 'Opt 1',
        '2' => 'Opt 2',
        '3' => 'Opt 3'
    ),
    'default'  => '2',
);
```

Instead of get

```
global $redux_demo;
echo 'Single Select value: ' . $redux_demo['opt-select'];
```

This will return 1, 2, 3.
But I want to get Opt 1, Opt 2, Opt 3. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You're declaring a key value set. The key is simply a pointer to the value. If you want the pointer and the key to be the same, then use then provide a non-multi dimensional array to denote that the key and the value are one and the same.